# PWA acting as share target opens a new instance unwillingly

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, web-manifest

I have an app that allows you to input some login information, opens a websocket to communicate with a backend. This login information is not stored (not by default anyway). This app is a one page application. (AngularJS but this should not matter)

The app is installed on the home screen and behaves as a share target. However when the share target is used, it always opens a new instance (new tab) of the app. This new instance is not logged in and I cannot do what I want to do with the shared link. For example, pass the data to the backend.

The `manifest.webmanifest` looks like this:

```
"share_target": {
    "action": "index.html",
    "method": "GET",
    "params": {
      "title": "name",
      "text": "description",
      "url": "link"
    }
  }
```

How can a one-page PWA act as a share target without opening multiple instances?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @lean No. I don't think it's possible and no elegant workaround.